# Motivation behind definition of PMF of function of $2$ variables

Tags: probability, distributions, intuition, definition

I am really curious to understand what motivates the definition $$p_{g(X,Y)} (g(X,Y)=z) = \sum_{(x,y)\in g^{-1}(\{z\})} p_{X,Y} (x,y)$$
where $g$ is a two variable function, and $X,Y$ are random variables.

The definition is given in the [MIT OCW video](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/resources/joint-pmfs-and-the-expected-value-rule/) on joint PMFs by Pr. J. Tsitsiklis but I am really curious to know if it can be derived or to know the motivations behind this definition?

Comment: The notation is clumsy.  Maybe it would be easier for you to understand if it is written as "$P(g(X, Y) = z) = \sum_{(x, y) \in g^{-1}(\{z\})} P(X = x, Y = y)$", or "$p_{g(X, Y)}(z) = \sum_{(x, y) \in g^{-1}(\{z\})} p_{X, Y}(x, y)$"?

Comment: That should clear any impending confusion (+1) @Zhanxiong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you understood the following three things:

1. The event $\{g(X, Y) = z\} := \{\omega: g(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) = z\}$ is a disjoint union of events $\{(X, Y) = (x, y)\}$, where $(x, y) \in g^{-1}(\{z\}) := \{(u, v): g(u, v) = z\}$;
2. $P(\cup_n A_n) = \sum_n P(A_n)$ if $\{A_n\}$ is a (countably many) sequence of disjoint events;
3. The probability mass function $p_Z(z)$ of a discrete r.v. $Z$ is *defined as* $p_Z(z) = P(Z = z)$,

then you should have no problem to understand (the correct version of) this equation (as what I proposed in my comment).